# How to count all symbols in a file?

Tags: java, symbols

```
public void countSymbols() throws IOException{

    String line = null;
    int count = 0;
    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){

        for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
        if(line.charAt(i) == ',' || '&' || '\t' ||'%') 
        count++;
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to count all symbols that appear in a file.. Anybody care to help?

Comment: Do you have the specific list of symbols ? If yes , then put them in a `List` and check with `contains()` for each symbol and increase count. Or , get the Unicode value for the char and if it falls in a range which is supposed to be symbol then  increment counter.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you provided? Seems that it indeed counts some symbols in the file.

Comment: your condition *"some letter is this or that or something else"*. This does not work in Java, here you need to write it this way *"some letter is this or some letter is that or some letter is something else"*

Answer (score 0):

you could rewrite your condition

```
if(line.charAt(i) == ',' || '&' || '\t' ||'%')
```

into

```
if(",&\t%".indexOf(line.charAt(i)) != -1)
```